# CSS media query for a specific ID

Tags: html, css

I tried to use media query within CSS that would work only on web front page. ID of the front page is defined within its body as `index`. This front page uses basically two columns (`.aside` and `.main`) and I want to avoid it on the front page but still use it on others.

When I try this CSS without specifying the ID, the `.aside` column does leave (on all pages), but once I try to add the `#index` (to use this only on the front page) it stops working.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    #index {
        .aside.col-lg-pull-9 {
            right: 100% !important;
        }
        .main.col-lg-push-3 {
            left: 0% !important;
        }
        .aside.col-lg-3 {
            width: 0% !important;
        }
        .main.col-lg-9 {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you are using a preprocessor such as SASS. You'll need to add `#index` to each selector individually e.g. `#index .aside.col-lg-pull-9`.

Comment: could you not overwrite the main styles in a style tag in that one page, for instance in css stylesheet `.aside{border:1px solid red;}` and at the top of the different page `<style>.aside{border:1px solid green;}</style>`

Comment: it is a web template using bootstrap so sass is supposedly included. I tried the suggestion with adding the index to each selector, but it does nothing either

Answer (score 3):

The ideal way to handle this problem is as Hidden Hobbes stated—by using a preprocessor such as SASS. SASS is transpiled to CSS, which is then loaded the browser. It eliminates repetitive CSS, which makes development faster, and code easier to understand.

Depending on what framework (if any) you're developing in, you should be able to find the appropriate SASS/SCSS module to use in your project. If you're currently not using a framework, I'm partial to suggesting HarpJS, which includes several preprocessing modules for CSS and HTML.

### References:

- SASS: http://sass-lang.com
- HarpJS: http://harpjs.com

Comment: it is a web template using bootstrap so sass is supposedly included

Answer (score 2):

the suggestion to add `#index` was good, but I kept a mistake in the previous code (dot before `aside` and `main`), the code below works well and it allows me to conditionally format the web based on the fact which link is actually viewed.

```
  @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
   #index aside.col-lg-pull-9 {
    right: 100% !important;
   }
   #index main.col-lg-push-3 {
    left: 0% !important;
   }
   #index aside.col-lg-3 {
    width: 0% !important;
   }
   #index main.col-lg-9 {
    width: 100% !important;
   }
}
```